# Grouping Reports on Custom Object Fields

Tags: reporting

I feel like the answer to my question should be straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm trying to pull summary data about customer stages, but it needs to be grouped by a custom field: Program.

At the moment my company has 10 different identical reports, each the same but grouped by a different set of programs (3-4 programs in each report).  I'd like to consolidate them into one report, displaying each grouping as a column.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Bucket Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_bucketing_overview.htm&type=5). After adding the field to the report, click the dropdown next to the field name, choose "Bucket this field", and follow the wizard. This would allow you to group several values into a single value.